# EF Core doesn't map UDF to CLR method

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core, user-defined-functions

Say, I have the following simplified UDF (in reality there will be a call to get next number in [SEQUENCE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-sequence-transact-sql)):

```sql
create function dbo.GetConsumerNextId()
returns int
as
begin
  return 123;
end;
```

According to [EF Core documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/user-defined-function-mapping), I can map UDF to CLR method. Here's what I have:

```cs
public class FLContext : DbContext
{
  public DbSet<Consumer> Consumers => Set<Consumer>();
  public FLContext(DbContextOptions<FLContext> options) : base(options) { }
  // UDF mapping method
  public int GetConsumerNextId() => throw new NotSupportedException();
  protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
  {
    // Register CLR method in DbContext
    var nextIdMethod = typeof(FLContext).GetMethod(nameof(GetConsumerNextId))!;
    //nextIdMethod is *not* null here
    modelBuilder.HasDbFunction(nextIdMethod);
  }
}
```

As you can see, the name of UDF is the same as of CLR one, so there must not be problems.
Say, I have this simple Minimal API:

```cs
app.MapGet("/api/consumers/id/next", (FLContext db) =>
{
  var nextId = db.GetConsumerNextId();
  return nextId;
});
```

Now things get interesting.
The *first* thing (and this is important!), that I do when I start app (in Debug mode), is a call to API (I'm using Postman):

```
https://localhost:5000/api/consumers/id/next
```

In this case `OnModelCreating` *never gets called*. And this means that DbContext has no way to register my UDF. Hence, I get exception:

> System.NotSupportedException: 'Specified method is not supported.'

It means that when I execute `db.GetConsumerNextId()`, I get what I'm asking: `throw new NotSupportedException()`. No call to UDF happens.

OK. Let's add some code to make `OnModelCreating` be called:

```cs
app.MapGet("/api/consumers/id/next", (FLContext db) =>
{
  // Query something
  var consumers = db.Consumers.ToList();
  var nextId = db.GetConsumerNextId(); //nextId is *not* null here
  return nextId;
});
```

`db.Consumers.ToList()` makes EF Core call `OnModelCreating`. However, *this has ABSOLUTELY no effect* - **I still get same exception**.
I tried to mention UDF name explicitly:

```cs
modelBuilder.HasDbFunction(nextIdMethod).HasName("GetConsumerNextId");
```

...and schema name ...and store type:

```cs
    modelBuilder
      .HasDbFunction(nextIdMethod)
      .HasName("GetConsumerNextId")
      .HasSchema("dbo")
      .HasStoreType("int");
```

But all this *did not* work. Whenever I call `db.GetConsumerNextId()`, debugger immediately moves me to `throw new NotSupportedException()`.
What have I missed?

Comment: Use the function in a query, not directly

Comment: Or add a body to the method that queries using a raw SQL query if you want to invoke it directly from .NET.